# The dependency mapping is not configured in WSDL resource

Tags: oracle-service-bus

I imported WSDL in Oracle service BUS (OSB) , once i click import button OSB showing below error in view conflicts

The dependency mapping is not configured in WSDL resource.

and

One of the WSDL dependencies is invalid.

Not sure reason of the erro. WSDL does not have dependencies..all XSD are in same place.

please help :(

Comment: Look through every line in the WSDL and all XSDs that contains the phrase `schemaLocation=`. Do any files have references to URLs or files that do not exist?